# Coupling a fancy ceramic planter with a cheap plastic planter with drainage hole + wick to have a simple self watering system for houseplants

Tags: houseplants, watering

I am trying to come up with a simple self watering system which could allow me to extend the time between watering my indoor plants such as Snake, Lily, Yucca, Dracaena.  This cause I am busy with work plus I travel a lot. I have a bunch of modern ceramic planters with no drainage holes. I would like to use:

1) a inner cheap plastic planter with holes

2) a wick

3) Rubber pot risers: (e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/Pack-Pot-Feet-Outdoor-Planters/dp/B07TVKSH23](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TVKSH23) )

4) Plastic saucer

5) Optionally: I can buy a little tube of the right Diameter, in a way that water will rise 1-2 inches above the top of the soil when bottom gap is filled up. I can have a mark so in the tube so I make sure to not overfill. I would use this curve to determine the diameter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action#/media/File:2014.06.17_Water_height_capillary.jpg)

[image]

I would like just to be able to pour water on the bottom gap, either by removing or not the inner plastic planter. I think a funnel would allow me to just fill the bottom without removing the inner planter if the lateral gap between ceramic and plastic planter is small, since plastic is flexible. What do you think about this solution? Would it work? My doubts are:

a) How large would you select the lateral gap between the inner and outer planters? I think it should be pretty small so water does not evaporate. But should I make it flush it with the ceramic planter so mosquitos do not enter? I am checking out some self-watering system, some seem tight, but it seems to me that they always have some sort of air recirculation, and are not air-tight. But I could be wrong.

b) Do you think the bottom saucer is needed? I am just afraid to ruin the ceramic pot if constantly wet, or water could pass by and ruin my floor/tables.

c) I am using rubber pot risers instead of gravel cause I think I can just put 2 or 3 of those to keep the inner planter elevated. Gravel would just take too much space and no much water would stay in the bottom gap. Does it seem like a good idea?

d) How far inside from the bottom does the wick need to go into the soil?